# twig print field multiple image in field templates

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

Here, I have attached my code

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
    {% if not label_hidden %}
        <div{{ title_attributes.addClass('field-label') }}>{{ label }}</div>

    {% endif %}
    <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('gall-wrp') }}>
        {% for item in items %}

  <a class="gall-img" href="{{ file_url(element['#object'].field_multiple_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}"> 
       <img src="{{ file_url(element['#object'].field_multiple_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}"></a>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

How to change `{{ file_url(element['#object'].field_multiple_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}` dynamically change value of `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have fixed this,

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
    {% if not label_hidden %}
        <div{{ title_attributes.addClass('field-label') }}>{{ label }}</div>      
    {% endif %}
    <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('gall-wrp') }}>
        {% for item in element['#object'].field_multiple_image %}      
          <a class="gall-img" href="{{ file_url(item.entity.uri.value) }}"> 
          <img src="{{ file_url(item.entity.uri.value) }}"></a>              
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.0` is the same than `[0]`. You can use:

```
{{ file_url(element['#object'].field_multiple_image.[yourVar].entity.uri.value) }}
```